# Hatcher's Definition of nonsingular bilinear pairing $(\varphi, \psi)\mapsto (\varphi \smile \psi)[M]$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This starts at the bottom of page 249 in Hatcher.

For a closed $R$-orientable $n$-manifold $M$, we have the cup product pairing

$H^k(M;R) \times H^{n-k}(M;R) \rightarrow R$,  $(\varphi, \psi) \mapsto (\varphi \smile \psi)[M]$

Where $[M]$ is a fundamental class for $[M]$.

He defines such a bilinear pairing $A \times B \rightarrow R$ as *nonsingular* if the maps $A \rightarrow Hom_R(B,R)$ and $B \rightarrow Hom_R(A,R)$, obtained by viewing the pairing as a function of each variable separately, are both isomorphisms.

> I am confused as to why fixing a variable gives a map into $Hom_R$. Let's say we fix $\psi$, then only $\varphi$ varies and the pairing becomes a map $\varphi \mapsto (\varphi \smile \psi)[M]$ which seems to be giving me a map $H^k(M;R) \rightarrow R$ rather than a map $H^k(M;R) \rightarrow Hom_R(H^{n-k}(M;R),R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each cohomology class $\phi$ you obtain a mapping that takes a complementary cohomology class $\Psi$ and assigns it to $(\phi\smile \psi)[M]\in R$, i.e.
$$ \phi \longmapsto (\psi \longmapsto (\phi\smile \psi)[M])).$$
Note this is the tensor/hom adjunction.

Answer (score 1):

The map $a\mapsto a\smile -([M])$, where $a$ ranges over all elements of $H^{n-k}(M;R)$, is a homomorphism from from $H^{n-k}(M;R)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(H^k(M;R),R)$. Notice that for a fixed $a$ the function that sends $b\in H^k(M;R)$ to $a\smile b([M])$ is, as you said, an element of $\mathrm{Hom}(H^k(M;R),R)$, and we are mapping the whole set $H^{n-k}(M;R)$ as such. Since the form is linear in each argument, you can verify that this mapping is a homomorphism of $R$-modules.